# Reading through code

Tags: java, arrays, trace

I'm having some trouble reading through this code and making a trace table to keep track of all the values. I've already compiled and executed the code but it only returns one answer. I'm tracing through using arrays:

```
foo(new int[]{});
foo(new int[]{-5,-3,-1,1,4,6});
foo(new int[]{-5,-3,-1,0,2,4,6});
```

this is the code im tracing through:

```
int a = 0;
int b = nums.length – 1;
boolean boo = false;

while (!boo && a < b)
{ 
  int s = nums[a] + nums[b];

  if (s == 0)
    boo = true;
  else if (s > 0)
    --b;
  else
    ++a;
}

return boo;
```

Just need help of what the trace table would look like for the three different arrays

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this is Java so I assume you are using Eclipse.

With Eclipse or any other good IDE, you have a built in debugger you can use to walk through your codes line by line.

Set the breakpoint at your first line of code and start the debugger. You can right click the line number and select toggle breakpoint or just double click it. Start the debugger by clicking on the icon that looks like a beetle. Your program will start running but it will pause at the breakpoint that you have set. There will be an arrow at the line number to show the current instruction pointer. After that, you can press F6 or click on the arrow icon to go to the next line.

When the program is paused, you can mouse over any of the variables before the current instruction pointer to see the current value of the variable. If you want to track multiple variables without having to mouse over constantly, you can right click and select watch and it will appear in the expressions window. If you just want to track all variables, you can open up the variables window.

You can jump to the next breakpoint by pressing F8 or the green play icon.

For more information and screenshots, see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

I hope it helped.